# Does UICollectionViewCell have a viewWillAppear or something I can pass data to

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have this in my view controller:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     CellSubclass *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     cell.dataObjects = data;

     return cell;
}
```

In my CellSubclass.m I have:

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    // You can call initWithFrame: method here as our base constructor of the UIView super class
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self)
    {
        // call functions that need access to data but data is nil
    }

    return self;
}
```

So in the lifecycle of my view controller, the CellSubclass gets called immediately before the data is ready. Is there a function like viewWillAppear or something that I can pass the data too?  How can I call a function from my view controller other than initWithFrame?  Can I pass the data in other ways?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds better use reloadCollectionView method in completion block which calls when your data fetch completd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds better to use your own configure method for cell in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     CellSubclass *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" 
                                                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];

     cell.dataObjects = fetchedMUtableArray[indexPath.row];

     [cell somethingConfiguringMethods];

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: I awesome that is [cell somthingConfiguringMethods] and the somethingConfiguringMethods is in the CellSubclass correct?

Comment: oh,sorry,yes. somthingConfiguringMethods is defined in cell implement file.

Answer (score 6):

**UICollectionViewCell** does not have something like that, but that is a subclass of UIView and that one has **didMoveToSuperview**.
I use it in production for some specific cases, but anyway it helps for some fast debugging also.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622433-didmovetosuperview

Comment: This is exactly what I needed in order to let me do some constraint modification once the views have been loaded. Thank you @Boris

Answer (score 1):

You should return the number of cells as `0` when you do not have any data to show. When you have the data ready just reload collection view.

In your datasource methods

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.collectionViewData)
        return self.collectionViewData.count; 
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Lets say you have an async network call and it has returned data.
In the completion block just reload collection view.

```
-(void)fetchData {
    [httpClient fetchDataWithCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *data) {
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Which function is that in: - (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: @chris thats your datasource method of  [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDataSource/collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:)

Comment: Okay true. How do I pass the data to CellSubclass and use it in initWithFrame

Comment: I have a parse PFQuery that loads a NSMutableArray in my view controller viewDidLoad and viewDidScroll

Comment: Not sure how to get the data from my NSMutableArray in my view controller into the subclassed UICollectionViewCell which uses the data in its initWithFrame

Comment: It sounds better to use your own configure method for cell.Define method that configures cell itself, and call that method in cellForItemAtIndexPath.